# want to store tweets data in .txt or .csv file using tweepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, twitter, tweepy

I am working on tweepy library to use twitter streaming API. I want to save all those tweets in a .txt file or .csv file.

//part of my code

```
def on_status(self, status):
    print( status.text)
```

when i write this line of code and run **python getData.py**(code file name) on terminal, tweets(with hashtags, id, http and some other) would print after 10 mins around.

but for saving data in .txt file, when i run **python getData.py > getData.txt** this. It took hours but didn't get any results.

I also tried

```
def on_status(self, status):
    with open("getData.txt","wb") as myFile:
        myFile.write(status)
        myFile.close()
```

but it is giving me error. Here's [a link](https://ideone.com/OKAzIF)of all those errors.

same i tried for .csv file but again getting error.

here is my full code.

```
import tweepy
import csv

####input your credentials here
consumer_key = ' '
consumer_secret = ' '
access_token = ' '
access_token_secret = ' '

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

#create a wrapper for the API provided by twitter.
api = tweepy.API( auth )

class TwitterStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
""" A listener handles tweets are the received from the stream.
    This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to      stdout.
"""

    def on_status(self, status):
        print( status)


# Twitter error list : https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes
     def on_error(self, status_code):
         if status_code == 403:
             print("The request is understood, but it has been refused or access is not allowed. Limit is maybe reached")
             return False

#create the stream
streamListener = TwitterStreamListener()

# Add your wrapper and your listner to the stream object
myStream = tweepy.Stream( auth = api.auth, listener = streamListener)

myStream.filter(track=['rajnathsingh'], async=True)
# myStream.filter( follow = ['135421739'])
```

I want to store it on .csv file of .txt file. How should i solve this    problem?
Thank you.

Comment: please post your full code and errors directly into the question

Comment: Looks like a problem with your connection, nothing to do with writing files. Maybe you've gone over your allowed request limit. Also, if you don't append to the file `'a'` rather `open("getData.txt","wb")` you'll overwrite it every time you open it.

Comment: @Peter I tried with `'a'` but that would give me `myFile.write(status)  TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Status` this error, and connection is not an issue. thanks.

Comment: All your errors say there's a connection problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to encode your tweet first before you save in csv.
It works for me

```
status = tweet.text.encode('utf8')
with open('getData.txt', 'a') as myFile:     
                              writer = csv.writer(myFile)
                              writer.writerow([status])
```